# Scope random order with pagination

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, random, scope

I'm trying to figure out how to make a scope that will return random ActiveRecords while also supporting will_paginate.

Right now each page view gets a completely different random set of ActiveRecords. Thus each pagination link, is actually just another random set of records.

How might I set up a scope so that it will be a random order that persists through pagination?

I'm guessing that I need to have some sort of seed that is based on time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using `ORDER BY RAND()` in your SQL to get your random ordering. If you are, then you can provide a [seed for the random number generator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> `RAND(), RAND(N)`
>
> [...] If a constant integer argument *N* is specified, it is used as the seed value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values.

So you just need to pick a seed (possibly even by using [`seed = rand(1e6)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001388) or something similar in your Ruby code) and track that seed in the session. Then, for the next page, pull the seed out of the session and feed it to MySQL's `RAND` function.

Keep in mind that `ORDER BY RAND()` (with or without a seed) isn't the cheapest operation on the planet. If your searchable table is small, you could generate a table with a bunch of columns, fill it with random numbers (probably generated by `RAND`), and join that table in to provide your random sequence to order by. You would provide different sequences to different viewers by choosing different columns from the random number table: for one user you sort by column 11 of the random number table/matrix but another user will use column 23. Keep in mind that tables (with a primary key) really are just functions on a finite domain (and vice versa) so which you choose is often just an implementation detail. Implementing `RAND` using a table will usually be pretty cumbersome but I thought I'd mention the option anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That's super helpful. How expensive is RAND(). I'm trying to have it so that my activity feed isn't just reverse chronological. I want people to run into things. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Cyrus: Sorting by `RAND(x)` (for some user-specific `x`) is probably fine but remember to look there if you start having database performance issues. You only need some way to associate the `x` with each user, stuff it in the session or the URL or whatever works in your specific situation.